# How to remove some duplicates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to remove all but the topmost value of duplicates in Excel. For example,

I have this:

```
A       B   C
R123    5   35
R123    5   14
R123    5   27
R345    89  19
R345    89  42
```

But I want this:

```
A       B   C
R123    5   35
R123        14
R123        27
R345    89  19
R345        42
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you defining duplicate? Based only on column B? Or does it have to match both columns A and B?

Comment: Do you need to actually remove the duplicates or can you just hide them?  Can you create an extra column?  Does it need to be done in place or can you create a separate table?

Answer (score 0):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx

While these instructions are for 2007, they should be essentially the same for 2010:

> To filter for unique values, use the Advanced command in the Sort & Filter group on the Data tab.
>
> To remove duplicate values, use the Remove Duplicates command in the Data Tools group on the Data tab.
>
> To highlight unique or duplicate values, use the Conditional Formatting command in the Style group on the Home tab.

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
=IF(B2<>B1,B2,IF(B2=B1,""))
```

Into cell D2 and drag botrtom right corner of the call down as far as you want to go.

Copy and paste values from column D into B